# How to use conditions in panda on a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently analyzing some tick data in a csv file, which is like this:

```
Time (UTC),Ask,Bid,AskVolume,BidVolume
2015.01.14 00:00:00.560,1.20104,1.20088,1.55,2.21
2015.01.14 00:00:01.175,1.20104,1.20088,1.46,1.46
2015.01.14 00:00:01.779,1.20104,1.20088,1.2,1.71
2015.01.14 00:00:11.236,1.20104,1.20088,1.47,2.21
2015.01.14 00:00:12.469,1.20104,1.20088,1.39,1.77
2015.01.14 00:00:13.219,1.20104,1.2009,1.39,1.1
2015.01.14 00:00:13.574,1.20104,1.2009,1.39,1.2
2015.01.14 00:00:13.877,1.20104,1.20089,2.14,1.27
2015.01.14 00:00:14.131,1.20104,1.20089,1.76,1.17
2015.01.14 00:00:14.660,1.20104,1.20089,1.76,1.17
2015.01.14 00:00:24.032,1.20103,1.20087,1.39,1.77
2015.01.14 00:00:25.134,1.20101,1.20086,1.1,1.4
2015.01.14 00:00:25.640,1.20104,1.20086,1.34,1.65
2015.01.14 00:00:25.943,1.20104,1.2009,2.21,1
2015.01.14 00:00:26.247,1.20101,1.20084,1.39,8.96
2015.01.14 00:00:26.449,1.20104,1.20089,1.71,1.37
2015.01.14 00:00:26.983,1.20105,1.20089,1.71,1.2
2015.01.14 00:00:27.518,1.20104,1.20089,1.74,1.47
```

I already know how to calculate the percent difference on the ask price, but I also want to know the exact date if any percent change exceeds 0.05. Here's what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('EURCHF_Ticks_2015.01.14_2015.01.15.csv')
percentChange = abs(data['Ask'].pct_change())
print(percentChange)
```

How do I get the date and print it out using condition statements in panda?

Comment: Could you cut and paste a sample of your dataframe (as text, rather than an image)?

Comment: How do you do it with conditionals?

Comment: And better than just text, paste in some code to initialize a minimal df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your own function you just need to pass a Boolean, and filter the original dataframe

```
percentChange = abs(data['Ask'].pct_change())>0.05

morethan5=data[percentChange]

Date=morethan5['Time (UTC)']
```

Comment: @RichardXie yw : -) if this is what you nee would you like accept it ?